# PHP regex preg_match separate variables in url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have string

```
$string = 'foo/{id}/bar/{name}';
```

and I am trying to do regex filtering

wanted output:

```
$matches = [
  0 => 'foo/{id}/bar/{name}',
  1 => 'id',
  2 => 'name'
]
```

I got so far: (regex is my weakness)

```
preg_match('~^' . $magic . '$~', $string, $matches)
```

> edit: there are *n number of {variable} in url

Comment: Why don't you use `explode()` for it?

Comment: Why using a chainsaw when a knife is enough? Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: `{id}` and `{name}` are placeholders, or literal? Maybe https://3v4l.org/eo0kO? (depending on definition of a "name")

Comment: @chris85  `{id}` and `{name}` are literal

Comment: Not an answer, but this https://regex101.com/ is very useful for debugging regex

Comment: Why do you want to "filter" these substrings? What is the final goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following `preg_match_all` approach:

```
$str = 'foo/{id}/bar/{name}/many/{number}/of/{variables}';
preg_match_all('/\{([^{}]+)\}/', $str, $m);

print_r($m[1]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
    [2] => number
    [3] => variables
)
```

Comment: Can I use it with: `$str = 'foo/{id}/bar/{name}/many/{number}/of/{variables}';`

Comment: Or even $str = 'foo/{$id}';`

Comment: do you want to just extract all values enclosed with `{}`? Like `Array
        (
            [0] => {id}
            [1] => {name}
            [2] => {number}
            [3] => {variables}
        )`

Comment: yes, all values with `{ }`, but array[0] should be whole url

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `regex` but it can also be done using simple string and array processing:

```
$string = 'foo/{id}/bar/{name}';

// Collect the values here, indexed by parameter names
$params = array();
// Remove any trailing and ending separator then split to pieces
$pieces = explode('/', trim($string, '/'));
// Every two pieces, the first one is the key, the other is the value
foreach (array_chunk($pieces, 2) as list($key, $value)) {
    // Put the values in $params, index by keys
    $params[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($params);
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => {id}
    [bar] => {name}
)
```

---

The `list($key, $value)` construct works since PHP 5.5. If you are stuck with an older version you can do it the old, more verbose way:

```
foreach (array_chunk($pieces, 2) as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = $pair;
    $params[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I see in comments to Romans answer that it's more than the two variables he needs. Updated my reply with a rolling search for more variables**

This can be done with strpos and strrpos too.

```
$string = "foo/{id}/bar/{name}/many/{number}/of/{variables}";
$pos = strpos($string, "{"); // find the first variable 
$matches = array();
while($pos!=0){ // while there are more variables keep going
    $matches[] = substr($string, $pos+1, strpos($string, "}", $pos)-$pos-1); //substring the variable from $pos -> ending }
    $pos = strpos($string, "{", $pos+1); // find the next variable
}
var_dump($matches);
```

strpos finds the position of the "/" and adds one (so that it does not include "/" in the substring).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

https://3v4l.org/pWXTh